# unending loop in java

Tags: java

I have here a code that does a search of the deepest pit in the array

I am to search the deepest pit by using the formula

`min(A[triP] - A[triQ], A[triR] - A[triQ]);`

where `triP` is the first point, `triQ` is the second and `triR` is the third.

What I dont get is that I am not able to see any printing. Or rather my code has an infinite loop.

```
int[] A = {0, 1, 3, -2, 0, 1, 0, -3, 2, 3};
int length = A.length, depth = 0, x = 0, minD;
int triP = 0, triQ = 0, triR = 0;
while(x < length){
    while(x < length){
        if(x + 1 == length)
            break;
        x++;
        if(A[triP] > A[x]){
            while(A[triP] > A[x]){
                if(x + 1 == length)
                    break;
                x++;
            }
            triQ = x;
            break;
        }
        else{
            triP++;
            if(x + 1 == length)
                break;
            x++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    while(x < length){
        if(x + 1 == length)
            break;
        x++;
        if(A[triQ] < A[x]){
            while(A[triQ] < A[x]){
                if(x + 1 == length)
                    break;
                x++;
            }
            triR = x;
            break;
        }
        else{
            triQ++;
            if(x + 1 == length)
                break;
            x++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    minD = Math.min(A[triP] - A[triQ], A[triR] - A[triQ]);
    if(depth < minD){
        depth = minD;
    }
    if(x >= length)
        break;
}

if(depth == 0)       
    System.out.println("-1");
else
    System.out.println(depth);
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Did you use your debugger and step through the code?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: A lot of this code doesn't make sense.  For example, your second nested `while` loop never executes.  I don't know how you'd expect anyone to fix your issue when it doesn't even look like you understand it yourself.

Comment: I stepped through out the code but I didn't see anything wrong (with respect to me) @tnw

Comment: There is no error found but it wont stop looping @K.C.

Comment: @MichaelParker The second loop executes when the next element in the first while loop is not less than the current.

Comment: I see.  Apologies, it is not easy to follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MichaelParker It's okay. I wasn't known for being a good programmer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your existing algorithm is doing, but if I've understood your intent properly then you're simply trying to find the index in the array for which `min(A[i-1] - A[i], A[i+1] - A[i])` is largest?  That can be expressed much more clearly as:

```
    int[] A = { 0, 1, 3, -2, 0, 1, 0, -3, 2, 3 };

    int best = 0;
    int bestIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i < A.length - 1; ++i) {
        int depth = Math.min(A[i - 1] - A[i], A[i + 1] - A[i]);
        if (depth > best) {
            best = depth;
            bestIndex = i;
        }
    }

    if (bestIndex == -1)
        System.out.println("Not Found");
    else
        System.out.println("Deepest pit at index " + bestIndex + " == " + best);
```

The output of this is:

```
Deepest pit at index 7 == 3
```

Comment: This was way better. But the pit can not just have 1 distance from each other exactly. Pit can be created as long as `p` < `q` < `r`

Comment: so, the indeces can be for example `5,7,8`. yours is just limited on 1 distance from each other.. But this is much near compared to mine :)